# Custom Role Allowing Things It Shouldn't Be

Tags: user-roles

I am creating this role 'grocery' for a client but it basically only needs to be able to edit pages and upload media. For some reason the code I have is still allowing the 'grocery' role to delete posts and create pages and do a bunch of things I DO NOT want this role to be able to do. This is my code, cant't figure out why it is not working. It is adding the role and letting me create users under this role, but again it is allowing the wrong things.

```
// Give capabilities
$capabilities_grocery = array(
  'activate_plugins' => false,
  'delete_others_pages' => false,
  'delete_others_posts' => false,
  'delete_pages' => false,
  'delete_posts' => false,
  'delete_private_pages' => false,
  'delete_private_posts' => false,
  'delete_published_pages' => false,
  'delete_published_posts' => false,
  'edit_dashboard' => false,
  'edit_others_pages' => true,
  'edit_others_posts' => true,
  'edit_pages' => true,
  'edit_posts' => true,
  'edit_private_pages' => true,
  'edit_private_posts' => true,
  'edit_published_pages' => true,
  'edit_published_posts' => true,
  'edit_theme_options' => false,
  'export' => true,
  'import' => true,
  'list_users' => false,
  'manage_categories' => false,
  'manage_links' => false,
  'manage_options' => false,
  'moderate_comments' => false,
  'promote_users' => false,
  'publish_pages' => false,
  'publish_posts' => false,
  'read_private_pages' => false,
  'read_private_posts' => false,
  'read' => true,
  'remove_users' => false,
  'switch_themes' => false,
  'upload_files' => true,
  'customize' => false,
  'delete_site' => false,
);

// Add The Role
add_role('grocery', 'Grocery', $capabilities_grocery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the 'edit' capability allows adding new posts/pages. A quick google shows there are ways to remove the creation capability; I haven't tested any of them.

Answer (score 0):

@[Cherry Austin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/106800/cherry-austin) right when you add 'edit' capability it will allow adding new posts/pages.

But, You can hide the add new page and also you can redirect the user if the user tries to directly access the add new page. Please check the code below:

```
public function remove_add_page_menu() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if( isset( $user->roles[0] ) ){

         $current_role = $user->roles[0];
    }

    if ( $current_role == 'user_role') {

      // this function will remove the Add New Page Link from Menu
      remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'post-new.php?post_type=page' );

      //User can directly access the add new page so you can redirect the user
      if( "add" === $current_screen->action && "page" == $current_screen->post_type ) {
        wp_redirect('htpp://www.url.com');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen','remove_add_page_menu' );
```

:)